# How to track with ormlite that database changes were made?

Tags: java, design-patterns, ormlite, architectural-patterns

I am working with the [com.j256.ormlite](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/) package.

My goal is to have a working database-file and a file the user can save with an UI-button to. To reach this goal I intent to track changes in the working file at the database abstraction layer and notify the user when he closes the program, that there is unsaved data.

How could I track if changes are made?

My first intuition is to write a decorator for the Dao Interface and wrap the Dao Creation in a single method, which uses my decorator.

The decorator could modify all update & delete methods. But the [dao](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/) seems to support transactions and seems to be a complex and long interface.

**How would you best solve my problem?**

Answer (score 0):

> My first intuition is to write a decorator for the Dao Interface and wrap the Dao Creation in a single method, which uses my decorator.

This certainly would make sense as long as all access to the database is done through the DAO.  I don't see why the transactions would complicate matters as long as used `dao.callBatchTasks(...)` which would call through your decorator.

Under the covers ORMLite uses 3 interfaces which represent the SQL database.

- [ConnectionSource](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/ConnectionSource.html)
- [DatabaseConnection](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/DatabaseConnection.html)
- [DatabaseResults](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/support/DatabaseResults.html)

You could write proxies for these classes which are lower level.